Special character (hashtag) in WPF CefSharp WebBrowser Adress string cannot be parsed
I have a WPF application using the CefSharp WebBrowser like this:
<cefBrowser:ChromiumWebBrowser Language="en" Address="{Binding ApplicationUrl, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</cefBrowser:ChromiumWebBrowser>

I use it to show either URL and local .pdf files, which usually works fine.
I ran into the problem, that when the ApplicationUrl is a path to a local .pdf file containing a hashtag, the Adress cannot be parsed correctly and nothing is shown.
This works fine: ApplicationUrl = "C:\cef\test.pdf"
This does not work: ApplicationUrl = "C:\cef\test#.pdf"
It seems to me like an encoding problem. But I am not sure, if its simply not possible.
Am I doing something wrong here ? Or is there any configuration that I can do to solve this ? I don't seem to find any corresponding solution ( property / methods) in the CefSharp API.
I  tried to edit the CefSharp BrowserSettings with different encoding like UTF-8 and UTF-16, but without any success.
Changing the datatype from string the Uri didn't help. Both datatypes work without hashtag and don't work with hashtags.
EDIT: Encoding the string itself with Uri.EscapeDataString or Uri.EscapeUriString like Clemens suggested didn't solve the problem. The string itself is changed, but CefSharp doesn't seem to interpret it in a way, that the .pdf is shown correctly. So it seems to me like a problem with CefSharp.
Any further help or hint would be appreciated.
Cheers

# is a special character in an URL. You have to encode it, e.g. by Uri.EscapeDataString.
